# How to initialise static variable using static method?

Tags: python, static

```
class One:
    i = One.get(9)
    @staticmethod
    def get(val):
        pass
```

I try to initialise the static variable using a static method, but the above code raises this error:

```
NameError: name 'One' is not defined
```

How can I initialise a static variable using a static method in Python?

Answer (score 2):

```
class One:
    @staticmethod
    def get(val):
        pass

    i = get.__func__(9)
```

Probably not the most pythonic way though. Note that the `i` variable is after the declaration of `get`. Since `@staticmethod` isn't callable directly (you'll receive a message if you do), you'd have to execute the underlaying function instead (`__func__`).